# The abstract type X has no mapped descendants and so cannot be mapped

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following model :

```
public abstract class AbstractBase { }
public abstract class AbstractBase<T> : AbstractBase where T : SomeOtherTypeBase
{
    T MyProp {get; set;}
}
public class Concrete1 : AbstractBase<OtherTypeSpecializationFor1> { }
public class Concrete2 : AbstractBase<OtherTypeSpecializationFor2> { }
```

But entity framework gives me the error :

> The abstract type AbstractBase has no mapped descendants and so cannot be mapped

In my opinion this should not happen since AbstractBase directly inherits from AbstractBase and the classes Concrete1/2 which are concrete inherit from GenericAbstractBase. What's going on here ?

Also, just out of curiosity, I'm wondering if the property of type T in GenericAbstractBase would be persisted by EF, just in case someone passing by has the answer in mind.

**Update 1**

Can anyone confirm that this is supported by EF ? I've seen this [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6be50b3e-5372-44aa-8af0-e00f88922ff0/how-can-one-store-generic-base-class-in-ef-code-only?forum=adonetefx) and according to Rowan's answer's this should be the case.
Thank you

**Update 2**
Same issue when the generic base class is not abstract.

Comment: Are `Concrete1` and `Concrete2` actually mapped in your configuration?

Comment: Yes they are, I have DbSets for these types, and I also explicitely registered them in OnModelCreating

Comment: I think this might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538004/entity-framework-5-the-abstract-type-x-has-no-mapped-descendents-and-so-cann

Comment: No it's not at all, he is neither using code-first or generics. Actually the EF team addressed my question, I forgot to post the answer here. I'll do it right now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the answer [from the EF Team](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2721) :

> EDM, the underlying meta-model used by the EF6 runtime to reason about
>   the entity types does not support generics. We allow non-generic
>   entity types that inherit from common generic types to be added to
>   models but as we walk up the inheritance hierarchies we stop looking
>   as soon as we hit a generic ancestor. You typically use this
>   capability to model the shape of your entity types using the full
>   expressiveness of inheritance and generics while on the CLR side of
>   things, however on the EF side this results in unrelated entity types
>   being added.
>
> That way you have defined your DbContext, from the perspective of the
>   EF6 runtime you are adding three different and unrelated entity types:
>   AbstractBase, Concrete1 and Concrete2. All the generic types in the
>   middle of the hierarchy have been ignored and therefore EF does not
>   know that they are related.
>
> With that limitation in mind, the exception you are getting is
>   expected, since AbstractBase is abstract and does not have any
>   concrete descendants know to EF. If you add a separate non-generic and
>   concrete type that inherits directly from AbstractBase, e.g.:
>
> ```
> public class ConcreteFork : AbstractBase {  }
> ```
>
> Your model should be valid again. However you won't be able to use
>   MyContext.AbstractBases to bootstrap queries that return instances of
>   Concrete1 or Concrete2, as EF is unaware of the fact that they are
>   related.
>
> **By the way, in EF7 we got rid of the EDM layer for the implementation
>   of EF and we expect to be able to support more and more scenarios for
>   actual generic entity types.**
>
> Hope this helps explain what is going on.
>
> Diego