# Why can't EF6 find "mapped descendants" when trying to create a migration?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations, dbcontext

I'm trying to create a initial migration for a small codebase with some inhertance (I tried to extract the issue from a bigger codebase ;) )
There are a few levels of abstract classes (with & without generics), but EntityFramework doesn't seem to be able to discover the type.

If I remove the generic (something I don't want to do) the migration is generated, and looks to be OK.

We're using the Table-Per-Type inheritance strategy.

The DbContext:

```
    public DbSet<NodeBase>         PipeNodeBases         { get; set; }
    public DbSet<NodeLevelOneBase> PipeNodeLevelOneBases { get; set; }    
    public DbSet<Node>             PipeNodeCoils         { get; set; }


    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
      SetUpDateTime(modelBuilder);
      SetUpConventions(modelBuilder);
      SetUpEntityConfigurations(modelBuilder);
      base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    private void SetUpEntityConfigurations(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
      modelBuilder.Entity<NodeBase>()
                  .ToTable("NodesBase")
                  .Property(x => x.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
      modelBuilder.Entity<NodeLevelOneBase>()
                  .ToTable("NodesLevelOne");      
      modelBuilder.Entity<Node>()
                  .ToTable("Nodes");
      modelBuilder.Entity<SomethingBase>()
                  .ToTable("SomethingBases")
                  .Property(x => x.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
      modelBuilder.Entity<Something>()
                  .ToTable("Somethings");
    }

    protected virtual void SetUpConventions(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
      modelBuilder.Conventions.Add<TablePerTypeConvention>();
      modelBuilder.Conventions.Add<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
      modelBuilder.Conventions.Add<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
    }

    protected virtual void SetUpDateTime(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
      modelBuilder.Properties<DateTime>().Configure(c => c.HasColumnType("datetime2"));
    }
```

The model:

```
  public abstract class SomethingBase
  {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
  }
  public class Something : SomethingBase { }
  public abstract class NodeBase
  {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
  }

  public abstract class NodeLevelOneBase : NodeBase
  {
    public string T { get; set; }
  }

  public abstract class NodeLevelTwoBase<TMaterial> : NodeLevelOneBase
    where TMaterial : SomethingBase
  {
    public virtual TMaterial Something { get; set; }
  }  
  public class Node : NodeLevelTwoBase<Something>
  {    
  }
```

The error I receive is :

> The abstract type 'Domain.Model.NodeLevelOneBase' has no mapped
>   descendants and so cannot be mapped. Either remove
>   'Domain.Model.NodeLevelOneBase' from the model or add one or more
>   types deriving from 'Domain.Model.NodeLevelOneBase' to the model.

I expected EntityFramework to find NodeLevelTwoBase as mapped descendant, through Node.

Comment: I found a similar question about this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29197744/the-abstract-type-x-has-no-mapped-descendants-and-so-cannot-be-mapped

Comment: It would seem that EF6 and generic inheritance don't mix.